# How to run magic commands in Jupyter deployed on Watson Studio?

Tags: db2, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I'm trying to analyze my datasets on DB2 on Cloud in the Jupyter notebook created in Watson Studio. When using the "%sql" magic for connecting DB2 doesn't work naturally, showing no such module. According to an IBM tutorial, it is required to run the "%run db2re.ipynb" command in a Jupyter cell before connecting DB2. But when I run this cell nothing happens and the "%sql" magic still not available. Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: To which tutorial are you referring?

Comment: @data_henrik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNfH0Wzx3is

Comment: Do you have that "db2re.ipynb" installed in your Watson Studio environment?

Comment: BTW: You can use that specific Db2 sql magic or this more general one: https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql

Comment: @data_henrik Hi there, I'm not sure how to install it to my environment. I have it uploaded to the "Asset".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two ways of accessing libraries in Watson Studio:
 - [Install or import a library, then reference it](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/importing-libraries.html). Note that you need to specify the `--user` option.
 - [First save your own scripts, then import them](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/add-script-to-notebook.html).

There are also the [built-in line and cell magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magics#cell-magics).
With that, I think I got it to work the following way:

1st cell, download db2re.ipynb to your environment:

```
%%sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DB2-Samples/Db2re/master/db2re.ipynb
```

2nd cell, install necessary library:

```
!pip install --user qgrid
```

3rd cell, run the db2re.ipynb notebook extension:

```
%run db2re.ipynb
```

Thereafter, I was able to run a `%sql`command.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed instructions!